# Probleme with Symfony 3.3.8 bundle creation

Tags: php, symfony, web

i try to create a bundle by console with symfony 3.3.8 after this version i dont have any problem with that but now i have one,

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BpWe.png)
[image]

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXO9R.png)
[image]

Any suggestion please!!!!!!

Comment: Can you add code of your composer.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your composer.json

replace your autoload part with:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

thinks i also execut the command bellow 
composer dump-autoload.

Problem resolve.